# Recommended books in geometric modelling?

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm currently doing a course in geometric modelling - an introduction to Bézier and B-spline techniques.

We use the book by the same name *Bézier and B-Spline Techniques* by Prautzsch, Boehm and Puluszny. While the exercises in this book is mathematical of nature, I would love to get some recommendation on
other resources, specifically related to the implementation of such techniques on a computer.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you're asking for a non-mathematical reference, or for something with code examples or the like, perhaps computer science or one of the programming Q&A websites might get better responses.

Answer (score 1):

Some other good texts are:

- Curves and Surfaces for CAGD by Gerald Farin
- The NURBS Book by Piegl and Tiller
- A Practical Guide to Splines by Carl deBoor
- Geometric Modeling by Michael Mortenson (pretty elementary)

The first one includes some code, and the second and third ones have quite a lot.